# How to customize displayed notification when received via FCM?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am receiving both `notification` payload and `data` payload when I send notification from back-end. Right now receiving default notification automatically when notification triggered from back-end.

Can this (default) coming notification can be overridden (like UI change or pending intent change)?

I tried both using `notification` payload and then with `data` payload (as later i got to know that notification payload not work when app is background),
but in end nothing worked for me.

As last resort, I am thinking of not sending any `notification` payload data and only send required notification data in `data` payload- is this going to work?

Attaching code snip with this..
(the last i tried with datapayload one value)

```
 public class AppFcmReceiverData extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ds";
        private static final String TAG = "4";
        private int numMessages = 0;
        private Context mContext;
        private String newsid;
        private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
        private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
        /*
            private ArrayList<NewsData.notificationData> notificationDatalist;
        */
        NewsData newsData;
        private Map<String, String> notificationdata;

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            mContext=AppFcmReceiverData.this;

            if (remoteMessage == null)
                return;

            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString());
                handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }

            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                    handleDataMessage(json);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        private void handleNotification(String body) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", body);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);


        }
        private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
            Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString())

    ...................................................................



          public class NotificationUtils {
            private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

            private Context mContext;

            public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
                this.mContext = mContext;
            }

            public void showNotificationMessage(String title, Intent intent1, Intent intent) {
                showNotificationMessage(title,intent,null);
            }

            public void showNotificationMessage(final String title,Intent intent) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title))
                    return;


                // notification icon
                final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                mContext,
                                0,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        );

                final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        mContext);

                final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                        + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title/*, message, timeStamp,*/ ,resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);

            }


            private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title,/* String message, String timeStamp, */PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

              //  inboxStyle.addLine(message);

                Notification notification;
                notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setSound(alarmSound)
                        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                        //.setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                       // .setContentText(message)
                        .build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID)), notification);
            }
```

Comment: "Attaching code snip with this"- it's missing in the post FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can omit the `notification` payload and just populate the `data` payload when sending an FCM from console/admin sdk.

You can override `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` on your android app's service- where you can receive and parse the `data` payload, and build a custom notification with custom pending intents. See examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived).

You can find details of how to build and show a custom notification on an android device [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification).

Comment: Note that `onMessageReceived` may not be called, when app is in background